# finding which files were removed from /tmp upon reboot

Tags: linux, tmp

Hoping against hope here, but is there some in-built logging mechanism through which I can find out which files were deleted from /tmp upon reboot? I could obviously tweak the shutdown scripts, but that's not what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

No, nothing keeps track about what gets deleted from /tmp upon reboot. Some distros even mount /tmp in RAM, so that's just gone upon reboot. You could implement such tracking yourself if you want, in your shutdown scripts, like `/etc/rc.d/rc.local_shutdown` for example.